# StrSubstitutor issue with $

Tags: java, apache-commons, substitution

I am trying to substitute the strings using org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor like this

```
      Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
      valuesMap.put("price", "40");
      valuesMap.put("product", "Shirt");
      String templateString = "I paid total ${{price}} for the product {{product}}.";
      StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap, "{{", "}}");
      String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);
      System.out.println(resolvedString);
```

Then I am getting the following output

> I paid total {{price}} for the product Shirt.

instead of

> I paid total $40 for the product Shirt.

I believe $ sign must be conflicting the way regex is been handled in StrSubstitutor.

Am I missing anything? If not then how can I get the expected solution?

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution as well, if I change the escape character then it will work

```
sub.setEscapeChar('^');
```